# How to take the duplicate records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here i have two document ,in this documents `childNodes` array `ID` is duplicate  means , i want to take the `userID` and `pedagogyID` of the record,as per my documents second document under  childNodes array `798` is coming duplicate, so i want to take the records

> Documents

```
 {
    "userID" : "A",
    "pedagogyID" : "100",
    "summary" : {
    "LearnProgress" : {
            "childNodes" : [
                            {
                                "ID" : "123",
                                "status" : "in-progress"
                            },
                            {
                                "ID" : "456",
                                "status" : null
                            },
                            {
                                "ID" : "333",
                                "status" : null
                            }
                        ],
            }
    }
}

{
"userID" : "B",
"pedagogyID" : "200",
"summary" : {
"LearnProgress" : {
"childNodes" : [
                {
                    "ID" : "789",
                    "status" : "in-progress"
                },
                {
                    "ID" : "1010",
                    "status" : null
                },
                {
                    "ID" : "789",
                    "status" : null
                }
            ],
}
}
}
```

> Expected Output

```
   {
"userID" : "B",
"pedagogyID" : "200",
}
```

> MY Code

```
 db.collectionname.aggregate(
[
  {"$unwind":"$summary.LearnProgress.childNodes"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"_id":"$_id","ID":"$summary.LearnProgress.childNodes.ID"},
    "userID":{"$first":"$userID"},
    "pedagogyID":{"$first":"$pedagogyID"},
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$match":{"count":{"$gt":1}}},
  {"$group":{"_id":{"userID":"$userID","pedagogyID":"$pedagogyID"}}},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$_id"}}    
],
{ allowDiskUse:true }
)
```

Comment: what should be the expected output?

Comment: @Anthony Winzletm, i hav updated my expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$summary.LearnProgress.childNodes"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"_id":"$_id","ID":"$summary.LearnProgress.childNodes.ID"},
    "userID":{"$first":"$userID"},
    "pedagogyID":{"$first":"$pedagogyID"},
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$match":{"count":{"$gt":1}}},
  {"$group":{"_id":{"userID":"$userID","pedagogyID":"$pedagogyID"}}},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$_id"}}    
],{"allowDiskUse":true})
```

Comment: Can you try again ? I've updated the `childNodes` to `summary.childNodes` ? If this update doesn't work please show me your query.

Comment: Again not working, it is taking to much time load after that is returning empty array

Comment: Are you testing with the same data that you've provided in the question ? It works for me.

Comment: I have 4L documents

Comment: Please try to test your code first with documents that you have provided. Can you show me some other documents ? Is the name of collection correct ?

Comment: Ohh sorry i have written wrong document structure,Please fine my updated document

Comment: Please modify your query and based on my document structure and update your answer

Comment: Updated. Give it a try

Comment: "message" : "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.",

Comment: Try `db.colname.aggregate(query,{
  allowDiskUse:true })`

Comment: query means what i have write , please update your code,because i am new in mongo db

Comment: I want to add total count of the documents

Comment: Can you please create a separate question ? I believe I have answered your original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collectionname.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$summary.LearnProgress.childNodes",

            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
            _id:'$summary.LearnProgress.childNodes.ID',
            count:{$sum:1},
            pedagogyID:{$first:'$pedagogyID'},
            userID:{$first:'$userID'}

            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $match: {
            count:{$gt:1}
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $project: {
                userID:1,
                pedagogyID:1,
                _id:0
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Comment: I have understand your code clearly,i have to add one more `group` like we have to add group by `userID`, from where i have to add, kindly update your answer